# jQuery not executing .then()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with a `.when()` `.then()` call in jQuery.

I am a teacher taking attendance in class by scanning student IDs. So I have a form that the ID scanner successfully populates and then hits the submit button. This successfully triggers a `.when()` call and the `.ajax()` successfully calls my code that populates a Google Sheet.

What I want is a list of students that I have successfully scanned to appear at the bottom of the page. I try to append to this list in the `.then()` call but it doesn't seem to execute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Student Automations</title>
  <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        var student = $('#studentId').val();
        var response;

        $.when(
          $.ajax('/logAttendance.php', {
            type: 'POST', // http method
            data: {
              studentId: $('#studentId').val(),
              spreadsheetId: $('#spreadsheetId').val(),
              worksheet: $('#worksheet').val(),
              studentIdCol: $('#studentIdCol').val()
            }, // data to submit
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
              response = student + " - added sucessfully";
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
              response = student + " - something went wrong";
            }
          })
        ).then(function(response) {
          $('#listOfScanned').append('<li>' + response + '</li>'); //does not work
          return false;
        })
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='studIdForm'>Student ID: <input type='text' name='studentId' id='studentId' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='spreadsheetId' value='mygooglesheetid' id='spreadsheetId'>
    <input type='hidden' name='worksheet' value='Sheet1' id='worksheet'>
    <input type='hidden' name='studentIdCol' value='A' id='studentIdCol'>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
    document.forms['studIdForm'].elements['studentId'].focus();
  </script>
  <p>Already scanned:</p>
  <ul id="listOfScanned">
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit:
Thank you all for so much quick input. I had a few things wrong, including the fact that the URL that I was calling was not returning JSON which meant that the success: statements were not being called. I removed the .when and have added some bells and whistles and ended up with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Automations</title>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />

</head>
<body>
<form id='studIdForm'>Student ID: <input type='text' name='studentId' id='studentId' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='spreadsheetId' value='mygooglesheetid' id='spreadsheetId'>
    <input type='hidden' name='worksheet' value='Sheet4' id='worksheet'>
    <input type='hidden' name='studentIdCol' value='A' id='studentIdCol'>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>document.forms['studIdForm'].elements['studentId'].focus();</script>
<p>Already scanned:</p>
<ul id="listOfScanned">
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var student = $('#studentId').val();
            $('#studentId').val('');
            $.ajax('/logAttendance.php', {
                type: 'POST',  // http method
                data: { studentId: student,
                    spreadsheetId: $('#spreadsheetId').val(),
                    worksheet: $('#worksheet').val(),
                    studentIdCol: $('#studentIdCol').val()
                },  // data to submit
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    $('#listOfScanned').prepend('<li>'+ student + ' - added sucessfully</li>');
                    return false;
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    $('#listOfScanned').preppend('<li>'+ student + ' - something went wrong</li>');
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#listOfScanned').find('li').eq(3).remove();
            $('#listOfScanned').find('li').eq(4).remove();
            $('#listOfScanned').find('li').eq(5).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than `response = student + " - added sucessfully";` in the success, return that value.

Comment: Try not using $.when and simply $.ajax or use actual JQuery with $.post or $.get

Comment: @Ahm23 " use actual JQuery with $.post or $.get"...huh? $.ajax and $.when are jQuery functions too...

Comment: It's actually a valid point that there is only one ajax call being made, so the `$.when` usage is unnecessary.  The `.then` can go directly on the end of the ajax call

Comment: @paulwillfixit it's unclear why you'd need $.when here. You can just do this append operation within the "success" callback. Or alternative you can add a .then() to the $.ajax call directly (and you wouldn't need the "success" callback either). $.when seems redundant, to be honest, working or otherwise. It'd only really be useful if you you wanted to wait for multiple requests to complete.

Comment: `$.when()` is like `Promise.all()`, it's useful when you want to wait for multiple promisses. It's not needed with a single promise.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there is no need of `$.when`, and you can add `.then(function (data) {})` to `$.ajax()`, so just do that. `response` is getting overwritten by the parameter `response` to the function given to `then`.